# How do you change the text from a canvas create_text in a function

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8, tkinter-canvas

I've been trying to change text from a button click. I don't know how but if you can either change the text in a function or do it directly from the button, could you please answer if you know how.This is my code.

```
from time import \*
from random import \*
from math import \*
from tkinter import \*

\#Variables

inter = Tk()
i = Canvas(inter, width=1100, height=650, bg='yellow')
BossHealth = (100)
BHID = i.create_text(170, 30, text=BossHealth, fill='black', fon=('Comic Sans MS', 15))
w = 1100
h = 800
Powers = \['Health+5', 'Damage+10', 'DamageX2'\]

\#Functions

def RanList(LIST):
listlen = len(LIST)
randitem = randint(1, listlen)
randitem = randitem - 1
item = LIST\[randitem\]
return item

def GetPower(Powers):
RanList(Powers)
return powers

def Damage(dmg,h,t):
h = h - dmg
i.itemconfig(i.BHID, text=h)
return h

\#Player Stats

PlayerHealth = (500)
A1Wait = (0)
A2Wait = (1)
A3Wait = (3)
A4Wait = (5)
A1DMG = (5)
A2DMG = (10)
A3DMG = (25)
A4DMG = (50)

\#Boss Stats

BA1Wait = (0)
BA2Wait = (2)
BA3Wait = (4)
BA4Wait = (5)
BA1DMG = (5)
BA2DMG = (10)
BA3DMG = (20)
BA4DMG = (75)

\#Interface

inter.title('Boss Battle')
i.pack()
A1 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Punch', bg='black',  fg='white', command=Damage(A1DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A2 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Rapid\\npunch', bg='black',  fg='white', command=Damage(A2DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A3 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Gun', bg='black',  fg='white', command=Damage(A3DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A4 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Rocket \\n Launcher', bg='black',  fg='white', command=Damage(A4DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A1.place(x=950, y=500)
A2.place(x=1025, y=500)
A3.place(x=950, y=575)
A4.place(x=1025, y=575)
i.create_text(90, 30, text='Boss Health: ',fill='black', font=('Comic Sans MS', 15))
```

I tried searching online but all the answers i found were either for a higher python update(i use python 3.8) or it was for a similar cause.

Comment: Please, format code tag.

Comment: _"I tried searching online but all the answers i found were either for a higher python update(i use python 3.8)"_ - this feature hasn't changed in more than a decade, and likely will never change. The python version is irrelevant.

Comment: Note that `command=Damage(...)` will execute `Damage(...)` immediately. For this case, use `lambda` instead: `command=lambda: Damage(...)`.

Comment: Also passing `BossHealth` as an argument to `Damage()` will not update `BossHealth` even this argument is modified inside `Damage()` because the argument is *pass-by-value* for normal integer type variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues in your code:

- `command=Damage(...)` will execute `Damage(...)` immediately without clicking the button. Nothing will be performed when the button is clicked later.  Use `lambda` instead: `command=lambda:Damage(...)`
- `BossHealth` is passed as an argument to `Damage()`.  Since Python use *pass-by-value* for normal integer variable, so updating the argument inside the function will not change `BossHealth`.  Suggest to change `BossHealth` to `IntVar`

Below is the modified code (removed unused stuff):

```py
from tkinter import *

#Functions

def Damage(dmg, h, t):
    h.set(h.get() - dmg)
    i.itemconfig(t, text=h.get())

#Player Stats

A1DMG = 5
A2DMG = 10
A3DMG = 25
A4DMG = 50

#Interface

inter = Tk()
inter.title('Boss Battle')

BossHealth = IntVar(value=100) # changed to IntVar

i = Canvas(inter, width=1100, height=650, bg='yellow')
i.pack()

i.create_text(90, 30, text='Boss Health:', fill='black', font=('Comic Sans MS', 15))
BHID = i.create_text(170, 30, text=BossHealth.get(), fill='black', fon=('Comic Sans MS', 15))

# used lambda in command option for below buttons
A1 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Punch', bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda:Damage(A1DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A2 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Rapid\npunch', bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda:Damage(A2DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A3 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Gun', bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda:Damage(A3DMG, BossHealth, BHID))
A4 = Button(inter, height=3, width=6, text='Rocket\nLauncher', bg='black', fg='white', command=lambda:Damage(A4DMG, BossHealth, BHID))

A1.place(x=950, y=500)
A2.place(x=1025, y=500)
A3.place(x=950, y=575)
A4.place(x=1025, y=575)

inter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, although i might add the unused stuff back in as the game is not finished. But still, thanks.

Comment: Just a question, what is lambda? I'm new to this and this is my first thing that is not a tutorial

Comment: @jincfer lambda is just a function without name.

Answer (score 2):

Typo error in line 31:

Change this:

```
def Damage(dmg,h,t):
    h = h - dmg
    i.itemconfig(i.BHID, text=h)
    return h
```

to:

```
def Damage(dmg,h,t):
    h = h - dmg
    i.itemconfig(BHID, text=h)
    return h
```

Comment: I do not understand in your game in Damage function. U cannot create both create_text. All I see is Boss Health: 100 at the start. then Boss Health: 50.

Comment: It isnt finished, and the error blocked all later code.